# Why I couldn't install the "quick.db" for discord.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js

I tried to download "quick.db" (for a few times but result was bad for me :P) for my own discord bot but I received an error in command prompt also I don't know how to fix it.. So, can someone help me for that?

So.. Please help about this, i wonder what is the solution :O

My node.js version is 12.19.1 and these are also errors:

```
C:\Users\cp\Desktop\Bot discord>npm i quick.db --save

better-sqlite3@7.1.1 install C:\Users\cp\Desktop\Bot discord\node_modules\better-sqlite3
prebuild-install || npm run build-release

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=12.19.1 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)

 better-sqlite3@7.1.1 build-release C:\Users\cp\Desktop\Bot discord\node_modules\better-sqlite3
 node-gyp rebuild --release


C:\Users\cp\Desktop\Bot discord\node_modules\better-sqlite3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\cp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )  else (node "C:\Users\cp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python checking Python explicitly set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python - "--python=" or "npm config get python" is "C:\Users\cp\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\cp\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Users\cp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Users\cp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:225:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Users\cp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:271:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:315:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:327:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\cp\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\cp\Desktop\Bot discord\node_modules\better-sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v12.19.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! better-sqlite3@7.1.1 build-release: `node-gyp rebuild --release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the better-sqlite3@7.1.1 build-release script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\cp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-29T19_16_25_587Z-debug.log
npm WARN advanced-discord-bot@3.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! better-sqlite3@7.1.1 install: `prebuild-install || npm run build-release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the better-sqlite3@7.1.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\cp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-29T19_16_28_369Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Use `npm install -g windows-build-tools` to install all the dependencies to build quick.db. 
( I would most likely mark your Question as Duplicate, but can't find the duplicated thread, wich surely exists tho )

Comment: I will try now. So, should I download the current version of node.js for discord bot? I mean 15.3.0 Also thanks for answer